# clicking on link opens blank firefox window

Tags: 12.04, firefox, default-programs, default-browser

i'm using firefox 14. 
When i click a link outside the browser it opens a new firefox window showing google.com(My home page).

I have tried setting into

> xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop

but that does not seems working.
Please suggest anything possible for this problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.  Use of any other browser specified in "Default Applications" works just fine but Firefox opens a default page every time and not the hyperlink I clicked on.  Just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 as of today :oP Found this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1959974

From the above link disabling the "Ubuntu Firefox Modifications" extension has a behaviour change.  Instead of going to the Ubuntu Google page it goes to the Mozilla google page, neither of which are my start page as I have FF set to load the last pages visited.  Hopefully this helps.